# Fix broken plastic on SD Reader

Tags: hardware, sd-card

So I received my Raspberry Pi today and as soon as I put in the SD memory card the tiny plastic that holds the memory card on the left hand side broke of. It didn't break of because of use of force, but simply by putting in the memory stick. Anyway, so I contacted the vendor and they said that apparently it was not covered by the warranty.

So I thought I'd check here at stack to see if anyone has got any creative solutions to hold the SD card in place. I imagined that maybe gluing it to place would work, but would be highly inconvenient. Anyone got any better ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy solution is to use a clothes' peg or bulldog clip.
I have seen the use of a piece of old credit card to put a fix in place - you could see if that would be appropriate.

http://raspi.tv/2012/how-to-fix-a-broken-sd-card-slot-on-your-raspberry-pi

Or you could try replacing the entire slot:

http://exartemarte.site40.net/?p=4

and

https://daniel.molkentin.net/2013/03/14/replacing-the-sd-card-reader-on-a-raspberry-pi-for-2-50-euros/

I've not cut-and-pasted the solutions wholesale as that would make for an enormous post, most of which might not be an appropriate solution.

Comment: I went ahead and put a credit-card on top the card without actually modifying the board and that added enough pressure to keep it down. Unfortunately the boar died a few days later -_-, and I ended up ordering a new one! And it is working great! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

You can glue a SD-to-MicroSD reduction there, they're sold with most MicroSD cards and you can get MicroSDHC cards, too. This allows you to remove/change the card when necessary, yet it is safely in place.

On the other hand, the warranty always depends on the laws of the country where you bought it, and since this sounds like a wrongly made piece, it should be covered by the warranty. Remember that it is not the company who decides what is covered.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced mine with an 11-pin slot. You can find the instructions [here](http://www.pieter-jan.com/node/12).

Comment: please explain the instructions in your answer.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the exact replacement part by doing the following search on eBay: 'raspberry pi sd card slot'. Hope that helps.